# Docker image not building; ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cleo' after updating python from 3.10.4-slim-bullseye to 3.11.0b3-slim

Tags: python, docker, python-poetry

I am using the Debian Python image 3.10.4 in my docker file which introduced a security vulnerability - https://app.snyk.io/org/abdulraoufatia/project/b31d4fe9-22dc-41f5-86f9-d99320f8a8de

With this in my Dockerfile, it works, however, when I go to update python from 3.10.4-slim-bullseye to 3.11.0b3-slim, an error is printed no module name cleo found.

```
FROM python:3.11.0b3-slim as base

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.poetry/bin" 

ARG DEV_PORT=4000

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install curl \
    && curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/1.1.14/get-poetry.py | python -

EXPOSE ${DEV_PORT}  

COPY . /app/

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false --local && poetry install

FROM base as development

CMD ["poetry", "run", "flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]

FROM base as production

CMD poetry run gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT "app.routes:app"
```

I have updated my poetry version to 1.1.14 and updated my dependencies within.

It works with a 3.10.5-slim-buster. Why am I updating from 3.10.4 to beta?
it is because of snyk recommendation [snyk-recommendation-vulnerability]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnyiH.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a`RUN` directive for installations, why not install whatever module `cleo` is? This error message is pretty clear: `no module name cleo found.` Here are the docs for that off quick glance: https://packages.debian.org/testing/shells/cleo

Comment: Your vulnerability report requires a login. Is there a reason you're trying to update to a beta version of python? Would updating to 3.10.5 fix the vulnerbility?

Comment: @Sören - it's worked with 3.10.5, thanks for that. I think the next step would be to update openssl within the image itself. I've attached an image, I hope it works, again, many thanks!